# Number of elements in $\{ x^{p^n}: x \in K \} \subseteq K$ for a field $K$

Tags: ring-theory

I have another question about ring theory.

Let $K$ b a field, with $p>0$ its characteristic. Define the set $T \:= \ \{ x \in K: x^{p^n}=x \} $. I had to prove that $|T| \leq p^n$.

---

*Research effort*

We may assume that $p$ is prime, because otherwise the ring would have zero divisors. The exercise stated that $T$ itself is a field. I tried several things to prove the statement above.
First of all $x \in T \ \iff \ x^{p^n}=x \ \iff \ x(x^{p^2-1}-1)=0 \  \iff \ x=0 \ \ \text{or} \ \ x^{p^2-1}=1$.

We see now if $T^*$ would be cyclic, $|T^*| = |\langle g\rangle| \leq p^n-1$, so that $|T| \leq p^n$.

My syllabus states the following:

*Let $R$ be a domain, and let $G$ be a finite subgroup of $R^*$, than $G$ is cyclic.*

This means that it's enough to show that $T$ is a finite set, but I failed to do so.

Could you provide me a hint please? It would be appreciated

Comment: If all you would like to show is that $T$ is a finite set, then here is a hint. Consider the polynomial $x^{p^{n}} - x = 0$ over the field $K$. At most how many solutions (counting multiplicity) can this polynomial have (given that $K$ is a field)? Therefore, how many elements can $T$ have?

Comment: He koen, Kasper hier. Was je hier nog uitgekomen ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A polynomial of degree $n$ in a field $F$ has at most $n$ roots.